# Laravel i can't display images in my home page

Tags: laravel

Below is the codes i am used for showing sliders in laravel website,but it does not display the images,

```
@foreach ($sliders as $key => $slider)
@if($key==0)
<div class="carousel-item active">
<img src="{{asset('storage/'.$slider->image)}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
</div>
@else 
<div class="carousel-item">
<img src="{{asset('storage/'.$slider->image)}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="">
</div>
@endif                      
@endforeach
```

Comment: I have php artisan storage:link commands 3 days ago,

Comment: Try to echo $slider->image by itself or check inside the database and see where it's pointing first. This will make it easier to track the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be sure your images in storage/app/public folder. if you are sure. Please relink:

```
rm -rf public/storage
php artisan storage:link
```